Problem in installing and using scikit-learn in Python
I want to run the following code in jupyter-notebook
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
before that, I have used the following lines in windows cmd:
python -m venv sklearn-env
sklearn-env\Scripts\activate
pip install -U scikit-learn

But still when I run the code, I get the error as:
No module named 'sklearn'
Any idea what is the problem?

This question is similar to: cannot import sklearn in python jupyter notebook. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you select the sklearn-env to be used for your Jupiter notebook kernel?

@kazcfz actually the problem is the same, but as you can there too, there is no solved answer.

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi The only kernel in my notebook is ipykernel. Shall I do anything about the kernel?

Working with a virtual environment (venv) involves installing all (and only) dependent packages for a specific project in a place other than your common library. You must tell your Jupiter IDE which kernel to use.

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi I added the .venv kernel. But when using this kernel, there was an error in the line for importing numpy. Somehow the following command solved the problem: pip install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib - while I am still using the ipykernel ! I am a little bit confused.

A virtual environment should be created once for each project. But the way you choose sklearn-env as your project virtual environment directory name suggests you believe you should create a new virtual directory for every package you add to your project. However, python -m venv  creates a directory with the chosen name and the essential files required to run Python scripts for that project. activating venv (\Scripts\activate) in your terminal will ensure that all new packages installed from the terminal will be installed in that directory. (1 / 2) >>

Of course, you can install all the packages without using a virtual environment, but this way, with time will cause you big trouble with version collision issues and a hard time managing projects. '.venv', which you set for the kernel, is a common name for the virtual environment (you choose 'sklearn-env'), so setting the kernel to run using '.venv' will not help you if the 'scikit-learn' package is installed to 'sklearn-env'. (2 / 2)

I added the .venv kernel. Using the following codes
pip install virtualenv

and then
pip install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib

and the problem was solved.
